# Why a line passing through a point not belonging to an algebraic set can intersect finitely many of that algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Following is from Smith's Algebraic Geometry book:

> If $V \subset \mathbb{A^n}$ is an algebraic set and $p \notin V$ is a point of $\mathbb{A^n}$, show that any line, $\ell$, through $p$ intersects $V$ in a finite number of points (if it intersects it at all).

If a line passes through the point $p \notin V$ and a point $q \in V$ then we have $$\dfrac{x^1_p}{x^1_q} = \dfrac{x^2_p}{x^2_q} = \dots = \dfrac{x^n_p}{x^n_q}.$$ How does one concludes that there are finitely many solutions for this if $x_q$'s are zeros of a set of polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of the line and $V$ is a closed subset of both in the Zariski topology. The closed sets of a line are finite collections of points, the empty set, and the whole line, and we can safely exclude the last two possibilities.

Also, I don't understand your system of equalities. Are you assuming that the line passes through the origin?

Comment: As you noted equalities are not correct. Btw why a line is closed in Zariski topology? Is considering it homemorphic to A^1 is rigorous enough to prove that it is closed in A^n?

Comment: @New user. Because by the definition of the Zariski topology the closed sets are the zeros of systems of polynomials, and a line is given as the zero set of a system of degree 1 polynomials. No, it's not enough to say that it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1.$ As an example, consider $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$, which is homeomorphic to the hyperbole $xy=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^2.$